# Json Parser in C | Memory access error (memory dumped) - Error

Tags: c, parsing, memory

I try to use the libjson Library for C and try to start this (https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/compiling-a-json-c-program-in-linux/) Programm with my own JsonObject. My JsonObject is a Jsonstring from a json File.

My output from the compiled code is: Memory access error (memory dumped)

How can I fix it?

My Code:

```
int main() {
    char *path = "./Paketspezifikationen/Default-File/DefaultConfig.json";
    FILE *fp;
    char *data = NULL;

    if((fp=fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL) {
    } else if(fseek(fp,0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        long size = ftell(fp);
        if(size > 0 && (data = (char *) malloc(size + 1)) != NULL) {
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            if(fread(data, 1, size, fp) != (size_t) size) {
                free(data);
                data = NULL;
            } else {
                data[size] = '\0';
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf ("%s",data); // return data

    json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(data);

    enum json_type type = json_object_get_type(jobj);

    printf("type: %d\n",type);

    switch(type) {
    case json_type_null:
        printf("json_type_nulln");
        break;

    case json_type_boolean:
        printf("json_type_booleann");
        break;

    case json_type_double:
        printf("json_type_doublen");
        break;

    case json_type_int:
        printf("json_type_intn");
        break;

    case json_type_object:
        printf("json_type_objectn");
        break;

    case json_type_array:
        printf("json_type_arrayn");
        break;

    case json_type_string:
        printf("json_type_stringn");
        break;


    }
}
```

If i use `printf("type: ", type)` like in the Tutorial I get: `JsonParser.c:83:9: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args] printf("type: ",type);`

Comment: you should try to debug aour program, espacially: a) is reading successful or do you end up with `data == NULL` b) is it valid json or does son_tokener_parse()`return NULL. Both might cause the crash.  And yes, the '%d' is obviously missing in the tutorial

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt it is insane, i comment the second part of the code, where the parser is try to find the type of the json objects and compile the code in CMD. I get this output: (null).

But if i start the Programm in Eclipse, I get the content of the json File 

why???

Comment: the path maybe?

Comment: The File is in ~/eclipse-workspace/test/Paketspezifikationen/Default-File

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I  changed it and now, if i compile the Code in Eclipse, i get null too. So i assume that, if i write ./Paketspezifikationen/Default-File/DefaultConfig.json is right. So for any reason, I get the content of the File if i compile the code in Eclipse. And i didnt get the content if i try to compile it in CMD. Maybe i write the CMD command wrong??? I write in CMD, in the same folder where the code is: gcc JsonParser.c after that i look at in the output file so: ./a.out did i forget somethink?

Comment: Give it the absolute path, not the relative path. Then see what happens.

Comment: You should try to use valgrind to debug your program, it will help you to find memory error

Comment: Note: `if((fp=fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL) {  } else if ...` does _nothing_ when the file is not opened. When it continues after the `if`, it can crash because `data` is null.